# White Screen During Joomla Installation

Tags: joomla, civicrm-home, installation

I installed the previous version of Civi for Joomla just fine. I removed the older version and tried installing the current version but a few seconds after the installation process starts, I get a white screen and it stalls. The error is:

(/home7/accountname/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home7/accountname/public_html/tmp/com_civicrm/com_civicrm/admin/configure.php on line 115

The configuration is:

Joomla 3.1.1
PHP 5.2.17
MySQL 5.5.42-37.1

As mentioned, I had installed a previous version in the same account with the same configuration without any problem at all. Any suggestions that would help me install Civi would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Did you follow the steps here: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrade+Joomla+Sites+to+4.5

When you say that you removed the older version, what steps did you follow to do this?  My first guess is that something wasn't removed correctly.

Comment: Thank you. I did refer to that page and follow the directions but I guess it's possible I missed something. I haven't had issues like this installing or updating extensions before. I deleted the plug-ins and the com folder so maybe I missed something. :/

Comment: You don't have to delete to do the update I think that's probably the problem, but whenever you get a white screen in Joomla try turning error reporting to development and see if there are messages.